# Classic ASP code to download .CSV file

Tags: asp-classic, download

I have a website written in Classic ASP
One page creates a .CSV file from a SQL database and stores it in the root directory along with a "Click Here" link to download it to the users PC

It has been working fine for many years and is still working fine when downloading small files, but now it comes up with a "THIS PAGE CAN'T BE DISPLAYED" error when downloading a .csv file (in this example) of some 785 records

The code is pretty short as below with the one Private Sub that does the download

```
<%@Language="VBScript"%>

<%Reponse.Buffer = True%>
<%
On Error Resume Next
Dim strPath
strPath = CStr(Request.QueryString("File"))
'-- do some basic error checking for the QueryString
If strPath = "" Then
    Response.Clear
Response.Write("No file specified.")
Response.End
ElseIf InStr(strPath, "..") > 0 Then
Response.Clear
Response.Write("Illegal folder location.")
Response.End
ElseIf Len(strPath) > 1024 Then
Response.Clear
Response.Write("Folder path too long.")
Response.End
Else
Call DownloadFile(strPath)
End If

Private Sub DownloadFile(file)
'--declare variables
Dim strAbsFile
Dim strFileExtension
Dim objFSO
Dim objFile
Dim objStream
'-- set absolute file location
strAbsFile = Server.MapPath(file)
'-- create FSO object to check if file exists and get properties
Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'-- check to see if the file exists
If objFSO.FileExists(strAbsFile) Then
    Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strAbsFile)
    '-- first clear the response, and then set the appropriate headers
    Response.Clear
    '-- the filename you give it will be the one that is shown
    ' to the users by default when they save
    Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & objFile.Name
    Response.AddHeader "Content-Length", objFile.Size
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
    Set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objStream.Open
    '-- set as binary
    objStream.Type = 1
    Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
    '-- load into the stream the file
    objStream.LoadFromFile(strAbsFile)
    '-- send the stream in the response
    Response.BinaryWrite(objStream.Read)
    objStream.Close
    Set objStream = Nothing
    Set objFile = Nothing
Else 'objFSO.FileExists(strAbsFile)
    Response.Clear
    Response.Write("No such file exists.")
End If
Set objFSO = Nothing
End Sub
%>
```

So something has changed in recent months

Ay advice much appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would check your server configuration hasn't changed. Has there been an upgrade etc? The value you want to check is `AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed` which will default to 200 KB so this might explain why some work and others don't, anything over 200 KB by default will fail. How to config this depends on what version of IIS you are running.

Answer (score 0):

Your IIS version and configuration might be needed to help but I know IIS6 introduced a 4MB limit to BinaryWrite. Try sending your file in chunks instead.

```
<% Response.Buffer = False %>
...
With Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    .Open
    .Type = 1
    .LoadFromFile strPath

    ' Send 256K chunks...
    Const intChunkSize = 262144

    Do While Response.IsClientConnected And (.Position < .Size)
        Response.BinaryWrite .Read(intChunkSize)
    Loop

    .Close
End With
```